# Can I use forEach within fs.createWriteStream?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to create .txt file which show the content of an array line by line.
At the moment I am using the following script but file is being created but it is empty.

What could cause the problem?

```
  var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('myOutput.txt');
    [1,2,3,4].forEach(function(item){
       wstream.write(item, '\n'); 
    }.bind(this));
    wstream.end();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can use `.forEach()` inside a stream write.  Your issue has nothing to do with the use of `.forEach()` at all.  Instead, you are passing the wrong arguments to `.write()`.  It does not take two separate arguments that are both data for the stream like you are using it.  The function signature for `.write()` is this:

```
writable.write(chunk[, encoding][, callback])
```

So, when you do this:

```
wstream.write(item, '\n');
```

your second argument is being interpreted as an encoding which does not work.  In fact, it throws an exception which you should have been able to see.

You can, instead, change to this:

```
 wstream.write(item + '\n');
```

This overall script works:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('myOutput.txt');
[1,2,3,4].forEach(function(item){
   wstream.write(item + '\n'); 
});
wstream.end();
```

FYI, I've tried this code on my own computer with node 4.x and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is not a stream, so there's no need to use stream writing. You can just use [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) and use `yourArrayOfLines.join('\n')` in as file content.

```
var lines = [.....];
fs.writeFile('myoutput.txt', lines.join('\n'), 'utf8');
```

done. Fewer lines, more obvious code behaviour (and note that the encoding is optional, it'll default to utf8 if you leave it off).

Comment: This seems more like a question about why their stream isn't working rather than a question asking for a different way to do it.

Comment: without them being explicit about whether their data is static or a stream, there's no way to tell. You've got the stream part covered, I've got the "if you didn't know about writeFile, you might want that instead" part covered, I'll let them pick which is the appropriate solution.

Comment: The "Your array is not a stream" that starts your answer is just totally confusing.  The array is, of course, an array and that has absolutely nothing to do with whether you write to disk using a stream or not.  Streams are useful for a wide variety of reasons no matter where the data comes from, whether the source of the data is an array or otherwise.

Comment: "questionable", perhaps, but certainly not "totally confusing": stream writing shines with stream input, and can confuse people greatly outside of stream context (streams are hard, there's tons of people who get confused by them). So, if you just have static data, it's a toss-up whether you want stream writing (if you're comfortable with that) or just "dump data to file". We don't know, they didn't say. Since the array in the question is not a stream, this is a perfectly fine alternative. The decision which one is better suited to their need is still up to the person asking the question.